# Twitter Bootstrap 4: how to prevent border from having gaps when using margin between two rows?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a table-like layout using bootstrap 4 and having difficulties understanding how to properly use borders.

Please take a look at the code extract:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 border-right border-primary">Name</div>
    <div class="col ml-1">Alice</div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-4 border-right border-primary">Surname</div>
    <div class="col ml-1">Smith</div>
</div>
```

It creates a table-like layout but due to second row having top margin the right border has a gap between the rows.

[image: 1]

What are the possible ways to resolve this issue?

Comment: Don'use use a margin, use padding to create the space.

Comment: @connexo, thanks for the tip! Unfortunately, changing `mt-3` to `pt-3` seems to change nothing. The gap is still there.

Comment: Hey @alexalok look at my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pt-3 to `inner col` class inside row for padding-top

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 border-right border-primary">Name</div>
      <div class="col ml-1">Alice</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 border-right border-primary pt-3">Surname</div>
      <div class="col ml-1 pt-3">Smith</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I wanted to achieve!

Answer (score 1):

Use padding instead of margin:

```css
.p-3 {
  padding: .5rem 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 border-right border-primary p-3">Name</div>
    <div class="col ml-1 p-3">Alice</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 border-right border-primary p-3">Surname</div>
    <div class="col ml-1 p-3">Smith</div>
</div>
```